# Разворачивание проекта Angular 2 TypeScript из репозитория TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, typescript, angular2

В проекте используется IDE Microsoft Visual Sudio Community 2015 (VS). Я не имею опыта в VS и TFS. Хочу разобраться как он работает.

Исходные данные:

- Есть репозиторий в Visual Studio Team Services
- IDE Microsoft Visual Sudio Community 2015
- Установлен NodeJS последней версии

Вопросы:

1. При установке с офсайт микрософт VS TypeScript стоит ver 1.8. Разобрался, обновил до 2.0 прописал в проекте использовать его.  Тут, ок.
2. Если посмотреть в репозиторий, то в нем нет папки node_modules (что логично). Но когда получаю проект локально из репозитория у меня появляется папка node_modules. Скорей всего после загрузки проекта, VS сама запускает npm install, это так? 
   И должен ли я после скачивания выполнять npm install вручную или VS  сама все отслеживает? 
   Так и не нашел, где посмотреть какую версию NodeJS использует VS? Если у нее свой внутренний NodeJs или использует глобально установленный?
   Какой порядок и какие действия я должен делать после загрузке из репозитория? К примеру npm install.